# Kohana: что он может фреймворк

Tags: php, kohana, mysql

Может работать с базой данных? Защита сайта? Без знания ооп с фреймворком можно разобраться? Стоит его изучать, если в дальнейшем придется разрабатывать сервисы с посещаемостью не менее 1млн пользователей.

Comment: бедняга ты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Может работать с базой данных?

Да. И там есть ORM.

> Защита сайта?

Сам по себе фрейморк безопасный. Багтрекер есть. Остальное зависит от программиста.

> Без знания ооп с фреймворком можно
> разобраться?

Если ты знаешь, что такое ООП, класс, объект прочие основы - то да. Тебе достаточно изучить паттерн MVC, который довольно прост. Скажу больше, хороший фрейворк приучает тебя кодить правильно. Всегда избегай повторений и думай на шаг вперед - вдруг надо будет добавить новое поле в таблицу, не придется ли все переделывать? Опять же таки, остальное применение ООП - зависит от программиста, но в типичных сайтах там ничего сложного и все на уровне интуиции.

Answer (score 6):

"Без знания ооп....."
"разрабатывать сервисы с посещаемостью не менее 1млн пользователей..."

и смех и грех... учите ООП